# How to store more than 255 characters in a cell when using php_writeexcel-0.3.0?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I am using `php_writeexcel-0.3.0` for exporting data to excel. Everything works perfect. But i just noticed that characters more than 255 are being truncated. I have tried using the `setversion()` function also.

below is the code snippet i used

```
require_once "php_writeexcel-0.3.0/class.writeexcel_workbook.inc.php";
require_once "php_writeexcel-0.3.0/class.writeexcel_worksheet.inc.php";
                //Export excel starts here

$fname = tempnam("/tmp", "Report.xls");
$workbook = new writeexcel_workbook($fname);
$worksheet = $workbook->addworksheet();
# Set the column width for columns 1, 2, 3 and 4
$worksheet->set_column(0, 0, 50);

# Create a format for the column headings
$header =& $workbook->addformat();
$header->set_bold();
$header->set_size(12);
$header->set_color('blue');

# Create a format for the stock price
$f_price =& $workbook->addformat();
$f_price->set_align('left');
$f_price->set_num_format('$0.00');

# Create a format for the stock volume
$f_volume =& $workbook->addformat();
$f_volume->set_align('left');
$f_volume->set_num_format('#,##0');
# Create a "vertical justification" format
$header->set_align('vjustify');
# Embedded newlines
$str2  = "Down\nHours";
$closedon =& $workbook->addformat();
$closedon->set_align('vcentre');
$closedon->set_text_wrap();
$f_change =& $workbook->addformat();
$f_change->set_align('vcentre');
$f_change->set_num_format('[Green]0.0%;[Red]-0.0%;0.0%');
$worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Work Order Number', $header);
$worksheet->write($SiNo, 0, $wo_number,$format2);
//$wo_number has more than 255 characters
$workbook->close();
header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel; name=\"Report.xls\"");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"Report.xls\"");
$fh=fopen($fname, "rb");
fpassthru($fh);
unlink($fname);
```

Is there any solution for this? or if there is any other `codeigniter` library or better php library available with example please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure. There is an excel column width limit of 255,  _I think this is a visual limit_ but `Total number of characters that a cell can contain = 32,767 characters`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep, guess the excel format is old. The maximum string length is 255 due to the Excel 5 format which is
still used. The long_string.pl example coming with
SpreadSheet::WriteExcel does not work for some reason. It must be
figured out why.

Comment: The library you are using looks a bit old and clunky. Would this be a better option https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ Or this https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel